# BST recursion remove delete java code moving the whole subtree

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

My BST remove code seems to have problem when removing with 2 children node, it removes the whole subtree. I went through the whole logic over and over again but couldn't find any errors.

Here is the code with successor method:

```
public T remove(T data) {
    // WRITE YOUR CODE HERE (DO NOT MODIFY METHOD HEADER)!
    if (data == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    BSTNode<T> dummy = new BSTNode<>(null);
    root = hRemove(root, data, dummy);
    return dummy.getData();
}

private BSTNode<T> hRemove(BSTNode<T> current, T data, BSTNode<T> dummy) {
    if (current == null) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    else if (data.compareTo(current.getData()) > 0) {
        current.setRight(hRemove(current.getRight(), data, dummy));
    }
    else if (data.compareTo(current.getData()) < 0) {
        current.setLeft(hRemove(current.getLeft(), data, dummy));
    }
    else {
        dummy.setData(current.getData());
        size--;
        if ((current.getLeft() == null) && (current.getRight()==null)) {
            return null;
        }
        else if (current.getLeft() != null) {
            return current.getLeft();
        }
        else if (current.getRight() != null) {
            return current.getRight();
        }
        else {
            BSTNode<T> dummy2 = new BSTNode(null);
            current.setRight(suc(current.getRight(), dummy2));
            current.setData(dummy2.getData());
        }
    }
    return current;
}

private BSTNode<T> suc(BSTNode<T> current, BSTNode<T> dummy2) {
    if (current.getLeft() == null) {
        dummy2.setData(current.getData());
        return current.getRight();
    }
    else {
        current.setLeft(suc(current.getLeft(),dummy2));
        return current;
    }
}
```

The result test shows like this:

```
[Test Failure: remove] [-0.31] : Unexpected content after removing 1 from the tree.

+----------------+
| Initial Tree:  |
|                |
|   1            |
|  /   \         |
| 0     2        |
|                |
|                |
| Expected Tree: |
|                |
|   2            |
|  /             |
| 0              |
|                |
|                |
| Actual Tree:   |
|                |
| 0              |
+----------------+
 

[Test Failure: remove] [-0.31] : Unexpected content after removing 1 from the tree.

+---------------------------------+
| Initial Tree:                   |
|                                 |
|               1                 |
|        /               \        |
|       0                 4       |
|                    /            |
|                   3             |
|                  /              |
|                 2               |
|                                 |
|                                 |
| Expected Tree:                  |
|                                 |
|       2                         |
|    /       \                    |
|   0         4                   |
|          /                      |
|         3                       |
|                                 |
|                                 |
| Actual Tree:                    |
|                                 |
| 0                               |
+---------------------------------+
 

[Test Failure: remove] [-0.31] : Unexpected content after removing 1 from the tree.

+-----------------+
| Initial Tree:   |
|                 |
|       1         |
|    /       \    |
|   0         2   |
|              \  |
|               3 |
|                 |
|                 |
| Expected Tree:  |
|                 |
|   2             |
|  /   \          |
| 0     3         |
|                 |
|                 |
| Actual Tree:    |
|                 |
| 0               |
+-----------------+
 

[Test Failure: remove] [-0.31] : Unexpected content after removing 1 from the tree.

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Initial Tree:                                                   |
|                                                                 |
|                               1                                 |
|                /                               \                |
|               0                                 5               |
|                                        /                        |
|                                       4                         |
|                                    /                            |
|                                   2                             |
|                                      \                          |
|                                       3                         |
|                                                                 |
|                                                                 |
| Expected Tree:                                                  |
|                                                                 |
|               2                                                 |
|        /               \                                        |
|       0                 5                                       |
|                    /                                            |
|                   4                                             |
|                  /                                              |
|                 3                                               |
|                                                                 |
|                                                                 |
| Actual Tree:                                                    |
|                                                                 |
| 0                                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
 

[Test Failure: remove] [-0.31] : Unexpected content after removing 4 from the tree.

+---------------------------------+
| Initial Tree:                   |
|                                 |
|               6                 |
|        /               \        |
|       2                 7       |
|    /       \                    |
|   1         4                   |
|  /       /   \                  |
| 0       3     5                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
| Expected Tree:                  |
|                                 |
|               6                 |
|        /               \        |
|       2                 7       |
|    /       \                    |
|   1         5                   |
|  /       /                      |
| 0       3                       |
|                                 |
|                                 |
| Actual Tree:                    |
|                                 |
|               6                 |
|        /               \        |
|       2                 7       |
|    /       \                    |
|   1         3                   |
|  /                              |
| 0                               |
+---------------------------------+
 

[Test Failure: remove] [-0.31] : Unexpected content after removing 2 from the tree.

+---------------------------------+
| Initial Tree:                   |
|                                 |
|               6                 |
|        /               \        |
|       2                 7       |
|    /       \                    |
|   1         4                   |
|  /       /   \                  |
| 0       3     5                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
| Expected Tree:                  |
|                                 |
|               6                 |
|        /               \        |
|       3                 7       |
|    /       \                    |
|   1         4                   |
|  /           \                  |
| 0             5                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
| Actual Tree:                    |
|                                 |
|       6                         |
|    /       \                    |
|   1         7                   |
|  /                              |
| 0                               |
+---------------------------------+
 

[Test Failure: remove] [-0.31] : Unexpected content after removing 2 from the tree.

+---------------------------------+
| Initial Tree:                   |
|                                 |
|               5                 |
|        /               \        |
|       2                 6       |
|    /       \                    |
|   1         3                   |
|  /           \                  |
| 0             4                 |
|                                 |
|                                 |
| Expected Tree:                  |
|                                 |
|               5                 |
|        /               \        |
|       3                 6       |
|    /       \                    |
|   1         4                   |
|  /                              |
| 0                               |
|                                 |
|                                 |
| Actual Tree:                    |
|                                 |
|       5                         |
|    /       \                    |
|   1         6                   |
|  /                              |
| 0                               |
+---------------------------------+
 

[Test Failure: remove] [-0.31] : Unexpected content after removing 2 from the tree.

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Initial Tree:                                                   |
|                                                                 |
|                               6                                 |
|                /                               \                |
|               2                                 7               |
|        /               \                                        |
|       1                 5                                       |
|    /               /                                            |
|   0               3                                             |
|                      \                                          |
|                       4                                         |
|                                                                 |
|                                                                 |
| Expected Tree:                                                  |
|                                                                 |
|               6                                                 |
|        /               \                                        |
|       3                 7                                       |
|    /       \                                                    |
|   1         5                                                   |
|  /       /                                                      |
| 0       4                                                       |
|                                                                 |
|                                                                 |
| Actual Tree:                                                    |
|                                                                 |
|       6                                                         |
|    /       \                                                    |
|   1         7                                                   |
|  /                                                              |
| 0                                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkVnp.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the conditions of the `if...else if...else if` construct. The first condition is correct (both null), but the second condition will be true if both children are not null, which is the case you really want to keep for the final `else`.

So change the conditions as follows:

```
        if (current.getLeft() == null && current.getRight() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else if (current.getRight() == null) {  // If ONLY a left child
            return current.getLeft();
        }
        else if (current.getLeft() == null) {  // If ONLY a right child
            return current.getRight();
        }
        else {
```

NB: this kind of problem can be easily detected with a debugger. Have it step through the code when you tell it to. Then you see execution moves into an `if` block where you don't want it to go.